# Does EIP 134 allow a variants on PoS where everything is at stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, eip

EIP 134 allows a transaction to specify which chain it is occur on.  In its original inception, this would be accomplished by specifying a recent block of the desired chain and a number 0-255 that specifies how far after this block the transaction can be used.

It seems this could be used to improve this double-or-nothing version of a sstaking scheme: A staker publishing a block, to prove his stake, could be required to include a transaction that drains his stake (acceptance of his block will later return 2x his stake).  This transaction can be used by other stakers to claim staked funds (at 1x the rate).

The problem with this that EIP 134 fixes is that, without EIP 134, a staker's transaction to drain his stake can be used by other stakers on forks that he's not betting against (staking is too risky).  EIP 134 allows that this transaction can be specified to only be used immediately following a specific parent block (only at the location of the fork).

Does this work?  Could a variable PoS scheme potentially be made from this double(or more)-or-nothing staking scheme?